# Repeatedly append to Array on Button Click Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a button  that is supposed to append the value of the cell's label to an array.

```
@IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject) {
     var cellLabelArray = [""]
     cellLabelArray.append(cell.cellLabel.text)
}
```

I assumed that as the more I selected the button, the longer the array would become.

Like : `cellLabelArray = ["label", "label", "label", "label"]` if I pressed it four times.

What I'm getting is that it just appends the text label once, what I want is to append multiple times, because the label changes.

it returns something like this: `["label"]` no matter how many times I press the button

How would I do this using Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that with this line:

```
var cellLabelArray = [""]
```

you're emptying `cellLabelArray` at the start of the method.

So declare and initialize `cellLabelArray` elsewhere in your code, ex:

```
var cellLabelArray:[String] = []
@IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject) {
    cellLabelArray.append(cell.cellLabel.text)
}
```

Comment: awesome thank you. I'll mark it as the answer when the time limit is up

Comment: How would you go about removing the same value? Since it is ".remove(at: Int)" a number would have to be set, tracked, and removed. Help in right direction to complete this?

Comment: Such an infuriating problem to be stuck at, but thank you!